# Breaking out from threaded loop

Tags: ruby, multithreading, threadpool

I'm downloading images from a (descending) time ordered gallery. I want to stop, when we get to the pictures already down.

```
require 'thread/pool'

def getimg(uri)
#...
  if File.exist? filename
    raise "Already done."  # something like this
  end
#...
end

pool = Thread.pool(4)

thumbs.each do |a|
  pool.process {
    getimg(URI(a.attr('href')))
  }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about passing a pool object and use `pool.shutdown`?

```
require 'thread/pool'

def getimg(uri, pool) # <----
#...
  if File.exist? filename
    pool.shutdown  # <--------
    return         # <------
  end
#...
end

pool = Thread.pool(4)

thumbs.each do |a|
  pool.process {
    getimg(URI(a.attr('href')), pool) # <----
  }
end
```

According to [the `Thread::Pool#process` code comment](https://github.com/meh/ruby-thread/blob/45611ccbce843700396be1d53d6f2c2a3be33691/lib/thread/pool.rb#L285):

> Shut down the pool, it will block until all tasks have finished running.

**UPDATE**

use `shutdown!` instead of `shutdown`.

> **shutown!** Shut down the pool instantly without finishing to execute tasks.

Comment: This sounds good, but it doesn't seems to work. I've tried trim! too.

Comment: @Kambus, I experimented this and it worked as expected. Here's what I experimented: http://pastebin.com/fgSw6BZT

Comment: Hmm this is weird! I have to get a page before File.exist to know the filename and that runs down regardless of pool.shutdown. Try to put p uri before the file check: http://pastebin.com/i7mb3PXQ

Comment: @Kambus, Replacing `shutdown` with `shutdown!` will solve your problem.